# Maximum length of a UI element string

Tags: buttons, tooltips, human-interface-guideline

I generally keep it as a good rule of thumb that if a UI element contains text that is longer than 20 characters (and is not an input field), then the contained characters should be a tooltip rather than actually displayed on the element.  This primarily applies to buttons and menu elements.  However, I've had some difficulty convincing other members of my team that excessive description is a bad design practice.

I wonder if anyone else has some similar guideline that they try to enforce.

Comment: Can you add any example of your idea so we are sure of what do you mean? Some screenshot of a shorter than 20 and longer than 20 interface would be OK

Comment: What is your justification for this rule-of-thumb?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of other 'rules of thumbs' people have? Or are you asking to try and figure out if this particular rule of thumb is a good one? If the former, while certainly an interesting question--it's not one that fits Stack Exchange very well.

Answer (score 5):

Rules of thumb that do not have a strong "WHY" attached are dangerous. Magic numbers too.

With respect, using example by @Abektes

> "32 as magic number ... It was rule of internalization department."

that rule could have been because the department paid for translation by the character? or longest word in any language? ... who knows why?

One rule of thumb I do use is to try keep high importance interactive UI items such as buttons and links down to two words or less, and a Verb and Noun e.g. "Add User". Why? *Because* this lowers the cognitive load, and thus supports fast and accurate scanning of a UI by a user.  Sometimes 3 words or more are required, but much rather be brief than explicit.

Comment: I always push for button labels in 'Verb + Noun' format (plus additional preposition or article). It makes it faster for users to scan and understand the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something international and aiming to add different languages, you may need more than 20.

Generally Russian and Indonesian language may need more character, there are some other but i could not recall them. I remember **32** as magic number from my past experience in a major international company. It was rule of internalization department.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is to use enough text to make it clear what the UI element is for. If I need more than 20 characters to make it clear, then I'm likely not doing the end-user a service by hiding the additional information in a tool tip.